# There is a gap at the end of the chart generated with JPGraph

Tags: php, plot, graph, charts, jpgraph

I'm generating a graph with **JPGraph** and it ends before it should, with a **gap** (it does not remove data, though). Not only that, it also adds some *weird numbers*, they look like hours and minutes, but some are different than my hour format which is `HH:ii`, so I don't know what they are. These numbers are not stable and change depending by how much dates the xaxis has (I guess).
[image: bugged graph]
In fact, there is no issue with a tenth of the data used for the previous chart:
[image: correct graph]
I've already checked everything regarding the data I pass to the functions, both the dates and the actual data have the same count().
This issue only arises when using the scale `$graph->SetScale("datlin")`, in fact if I use `textlin` this does not happen, but the tick count is not automatic, like with the `datlin` scale.

I don't know if it's a bug in the library or if I'm doing something wrong.

Here is the code for the graph generation:

```php
$graph = new Graph\Graph(1100, 600);
$graph->SetMargin(100, 100, 100, 100);
$graph->SetScale("datlin");
if (count($dates) != 0)
    $graph->xaxis->SetTextTickInterval(count($dates) / (count($dates) / 10)); //Is this even needed, since I have the datlin? Removing it does not fix my problem nor does it change anything.
$graph->xaxis->SetTickLabels($dates);
$graph->xaxis->SetLabelAngle(90);
$graph->xaxis->SetFont(FF_ARIAL, FS_NORMAL, 8);
$graph->xaxis->SetTitle('Tempo [gg-MM-aaaa hh:mm]', 'center');
$graph->xaxis->SetTitleSide(SIDE_BOTTOM);
$graph->xaxis->SetPos('min');
$graph->xaxis->title->SetMargin(100);
$graph->xaxis->title->SetFont(FF_ARIAL, FS_BOLD, 10);

//This is the ugly solution, but it only removes the label with the weird numbers, not the gap created at the end.
$graph->xaxis->HideFirstTickLabel(false);
$graph->xaxis->HideLastTickLabel(false);


$graph->xgrid->Show();


$sensorDataWithoutFirst = array_slice($data, 1, null, true);
$index = 0;
foreach ($yAxisTypes as $_ => $type) {
    ... creating y axis ...
}

//Converti i valori in una matrice di double, rimuove anche le chiavi
$firstSensorValues = array_values(array_map(function ($value) {
    if (is_bool($value))
        return false;
    return (double) $value;
}, $data[$sezioneSensorList[0]->id]));

$p1 = new Plot\LinePlot($firstSensorValues);
$p1->SetColor($colors[0]);
$p1->SetLegend($sezioneSensorList[0]->Nome);
$graph->yaxis->title->SetFont(FF_ARIAL, FS_BOLD, 10);
//Spostalo dove può essere visto
$graph->yaxis->title->SetMargin(40);
$graph->yaxis->title->Set($sezioneSensorList[0]->tipoSensore->nome . " [" . $sezioneSensorList[0]->tipoSensore->UnitaMisura . "]");
$graph->Add($p1);

$yAxisTypes = array_slice($yAxisTypes, 1);

$colorIndex = 1;


//The remaining code is for creating plots, probably not related to my issue, but I kept it anyway:
foreach ($sensorDataWithoutFirst as $id => $values) {
    //Obtain the sensor based on its id within the sectionSensorList (it is an array not a collection)
    $sensoreCorrente = $sezioneSensorList[array_search($id, array_column($sezioneSensorList, 'id'))];
    //Convert values into an array of doubles
    $values = array_map(function ($value) {
        if (is_bool($value))
            return false;
        return (double) $value;
    }, array_values($values));
    $plot = new Plot\LinePlot($values);
    $plot->SetColor($colors[$colorIndex]);
    $plot->SetLegend($sensoreCorrente->Nome);
    //Instead of adding the graph to the y-axis by index, add it to the y-axis containing the sensor type
    //If the sensor type is the same as the first one (the one that uses the default y-axis and not the yn-axis array), draw the graph on the default y-axis
    if ($sensoreCorrente->tipoSensore->nome == $sezioneSensorList[0]->tipoSensore->nome) {
        $graph->Add($plot);
    }
    foreach ($yAxisTypes as $typeIndex => $type) {
        //if the sensor type is the same as the current y-axis, draw the graph on that y-axis
        if ($type->nome == $sensoreCorrente->tipoSensore->nome) {
            $graph->AddY($typeIndex, $plot);
        }
    }
    $colorIndex = ($colorIndex + 1) % count($colors);
}

$graph->legend->Pos(0.5, 0.05, 'center', 'top');
$graph->Stroke($chartImagePath);
... other code not influencing this ...
```